# Parsing Text containing spaces and - in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Dear Community Member,

I am new to MS Access, and am currently building a simple database for a client as a part of a project. We get data from an outside source in the following format:

Customer Key: 01105 105837-19-9

City/State/Zip: LEESBURG FL  34788-3522

I need to separate our Customer Key into four columns to so it looks like
CORP: 1105

Account: 105837

Cust: 19

House: 9

Similarly for City/State/Zip
City: Leesburg
State: FL
Zip: 34788-3522

I have been able to use Left, Instr and Right Functions to separate out the left and right extreme information

CORP: Left([NCOA_RAW].[custkey],InStr([NCOA_RAW].[custkey]," ")-1)

CUST: Right([ncoa_raw].[custkey],Len([ncoa_raw].[custkey])-InStr(1,[ncoa_raw].[CUSTKEY],"-")-0)

I am having trouble parsing the House information as it contains spaces and -. Can you advise, how I can go about separating out such information. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
JHaider

Comment: how well standardized is the input?  Are the elements of Customer key always the same length?  If so, look at the MID function.  The City/State/Zip may be harder because the city name may include spaces - for that, look at the InStrRev function.

Answer (score 1):

If the state is always 2 characters, the following should work:

```
ZIP: Mid([city/state/zip],InStrRev([city/state/zip]," ")+1)
State: Mid([city/state/zip],InStrRev([city/state/zip]," ")-2,2)
City: Left([city/state/zip],Len([city/state/zip])-InStrRev([city/state/zip]," ")-2)
```

Depending on the makeup of the customer key, you can do similar things there